# Meta-data from SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to query a SQLite database for basic meta data such as:

- Last date/time updated
- Hash of database to indicate "state"

I am just looking for a simple, infrastructural way to have a script evaluate different databases and take a reasonable point of view on whether they are the same "state" as other databases in a different environment (PROD and DEV for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, if no update, new record, or any change is made to the SQLite database file, the last modified time of the file doesn't change. So the last modified time should suffice for the time of any change made to database.

If 2 database files with same state are only accessed for reading, their modified times are always the same.

Similarly you get the file sizes for comparison.

You can use the whole file to calculate hash. If you consider same data in the database as the same "state" regardless of any difference in the past, then maybe you want hash of the all records in database, which is probably not simple.

Comment: Thanks Griddoor, good suggestions I'm going to mark this as the right answer. SQLite's life as a **file** has some advantages for this goal. :)